# Auto saving run configuration android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am making espresso tests for an android app and I wonder if there's a way to automatically save the run configurations for each test on Android Studio? ie, is there a way in which each time I run a new test, the configurations will save without me having to manually do so?

Answer (score 1):

When you view the run configuration dialog in Android Studio, there should be a "share" checkbox at the top right of the dialog.  If you check this box, it will save the configuration into the .idea folder of the project.  See "runConfigurations" folder and the runConfigurations.xml file under .idea.  If save or check these files into source control, you will be able to share and reuse these configurations when you import the project again.